# How to write system of vector equations in a rotated frame?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, vectors, linear-algebra

I have a system of vector equations:
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} = \vec{B} \\
\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = \vec{C} + \psi \vec{B},
$$
where $\psi$ is a scalar function. Say I want to solve this equation in a different coordinate system (which is just a rotation) defined by the transformation matrix $\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}$. How would I go about transforming this system of equations to that reference frame? Is it just a case of solving instead:
$$
\frac{\partial (\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot\vec{A})}{\partial t} = \underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot \vec{B} \\ 
\frac{\partial (\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}\cdot \vec{B})}{\partial t}=\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}\cdot\vec{C}+\psi\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}\cdot\vec{B}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides with $\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}^{-1}$ to arrive at the same equations you started with.

$$\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} = \vec{B} \\
\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = \vec{C} + \psi \vec{B},$$

This is because vector equations should be coordinate frame free and should be valid regardless of the basis-vectors used, as long as you are *consistent* with all the quantities involved.

ALso not that the derivative operator in a linear operator in terms of $\partial ( \underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot A) = \underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot \partial A$ and that is why

$$\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}^{-1} \frac{\partial (\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot\vec{A})}{\partial t} = \underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}^{-1} (\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot \vec{B}) \\
\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}^{-1} \frac{\partial (\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot \vec{B})}{\partial t} = \underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}^{-1} (\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot\vec{C}) + \psi \underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}}^{-1} (\underline{\underline{\mathbf{T}}} \cdot \vec{B}),$$

is equivalent to the original equations.